# 64bit libjvm.dylib on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, jvm, java-native-interface

I have a Java project that needs to load some native dynamic libraries.

I run a 64bit JVM, I need to load 64bit dynamic libraries but I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/mariosangiorgio/Downloads/darwin_x86_64/libminisat.dylib:  Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib   Referenced from: /Users/mariosangiorgio/Downloads/darwin_x86_64/libminisat.dylib   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:  /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/../Libraries/libjvm.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

These are the version of the JVM:

```
mariosangiorgio:MacOS/ $ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01-451, mixed mode)
```

the library I need

```
$ lipo -info ibminisat.dylib
Non-fat file: libminisat.dylib is architecture: x86_64
```

and the library of my JVM, which is causing the problem:

```
$ lipo -info libjvm.dylib
Non-fat file: libjvm.dylib is architecture: i386
```

I don't know if it may be the cause of my issue but I am running everything from within Eclipse. Minisat is used by an Eclipse plugin.

Do you have any idea on where can I get the 64bit version of `libjvm.dylib` or if there is another way I could solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure Eclipse is using 64-bit java?

Comment: And when you say "running everything from within Eclipse", are you starting a *new* Eclipse instance - that is, you have a run / debug configuration that is an "Eclipse Application" to debug a plug-in you're writing?

Comment: @EdwardThomson libminisat.dylib is required by an Eclipse plug-in I need to use

Comment: @tcb how can I double check that Eclipse is using 64-bit Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get everything work by installing the [latest version of the Oracle JDK available](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).